# Common algorithm example (with counters)

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to find an example of a common algorithm (the sort that you could find in a basic computer science / telecoms text book) which meets the following conditions:

- there is a counter *a* (which could count integers, bits, time etc.)
- *a* is reset when either: (i) *a* reaches or exceeds a predefined threshold *x* or (ii) another event occurs.

Ideally (although not strictly necessary) the "other event" that causes *a* to reset would be another counter *b*. Both *a* and *b* would reset if *b* reaches a predefined threshold *y* (and similarly, both *a* and *b* would reset if *a* reaches the predefined threshold *x*). This could be presented by:

```
Initialize x and y thresholds

while (true) 

    if (*particular event relevant to a*) 
       a++;

    if (*particular event relevant to b*) 
       b++;

    if (a>=x) OR (b>=y) 
         *Something happens*
         a=0;
         b=0;
```

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Many thanks

Comment: what about: more timers generated with single timer/counter , PWM generator , frequency generator,...

Comment: `Event` as in _external event_ or as in _internal condition_? (Xilinx app note "counter examples" comes to mind - from year before the www.)

Comment: @greybeard - an internal condition. Perhaps a better explanation of what I'm after is an implementation of two variables racing to get to threshold. Once either variable gets to its threshold, they both reset.

Answer (score 0):

What about higher level network packet reception?

1. `received_samples=0`
2. you ask your lower level layer to receive `min(maximum_packet_size, request_length - received_bytes )`

   a. you take the bytes you've got and add them to your buffer, `received_bytes += n_bytes_received_this_time`

   b. if the number of received bytes hasn't reached the size you need, you repeat 2.

   (c.) If an error occurs, you handle that.

Comment: Thanks Marcus. This is useful.